# Use value of some variables of parent bash script in new bash script being created by parent

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to create a new bash script (with some commands and variables), from another bash script but the issue is that there are some variable specific to new script that I need as well as I need to use the variable's values of parent script, for now only a new bash script is being created but values of parent scripts aren't copied instead whole variable is being copied.

```
# commnads ...... xyz for parent script

PATH="this/path/I/want/in/new/script"

echo "#### Setting up post-receive hooks ####"

cd hooks

cat >post-receive << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev ref

branchname=${ref#refs/heads/}

# the path is actually for first script, how I can get the value for PATH only
GIT_WORK_TREE=$PATH git checkout ${branchname} -f
EOF
chmod +x post-receive
```

here is the file being created,

```
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev ref

branchname=${ref#refs/heads/}

GIT_WORK_TREE=$PATH git checkout ${branchname} -f
               #^ i need the actual value here not the variable
```

Comment: Only read the title but i guess use `export`. Actually i just read the question, remove the quotes around `EOF`. From man bash `If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion` where word is EOF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You quoted the here document delimiter, so you disabled *all* parameter expansions, including `$PATH`. If you want to expand any parameters, you'll have to leave the delimiter unquoted and explicitly escape the `$` for the ones you don't want expanded.

Since you don't actually want to override *your* `PATH`, don't use `PATH` as the variable name; use a lowercase name.

```
path="this/path/I/want/in/new/script"

echo "#### Setting up post-receive hooks ####"

cd hooks

cat >post-receive <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev ref

branchname=\${ref#refs/heads/}

GIT_WORK_TREE=$path git checkout \${branchname} -f
EOF
chmod +x post-receive
```

Answer (score -2):

Put single brackets around the part you want to run and get the value from. Single brackets run whatever is inside in a subshell and then returns that as a value.

```
    GIT_WORK_TREE=$($PATH git checkout ${branchname} -f)
```